# How to put a text on picture in C with SDL?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-ttf

I am making bowling table in C with sdl (bowling table is bmp file), and I need to write statistic in table, and player name also. I tried with `SDL_ttf` to write text on screen, but it can't write on picture, in my case in table. One silly thing is to make a little bmps for every value, but it is 300 different numbers, so no way.

Answer (score 0):

in SDL, a font is a surface like other surfaces.

So if you want to be able to see your font, you just have to blit it AFTER the surface of the table.

Another way would be to use a font spritesheet.